# kinetic js - how do I modify attributes dynamically (onmouseover)

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have the following code, however the position doesn't vary with a mouseover - what am I missing?

```
function drawOverlay() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: 'overlay'});
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 239, y: 75,
        width: 100, height: 50,
        fill: 'green', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4
    });
    rect.on('mouseover', function(e) {rect.setPosition({x: 50, y: 5 0});});

    layer.add(rect);
    stage.add(layer);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. Your y value has a space in it: "5 0" vs. "50", which causes a javascript parsing error.
2. You need to redraw the layer after changing the position of the node.

So try this:

```
rect.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    rect.setPosition({x: 50, y: 50}); 
    layer.draw(); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much - the layer.draw() in particular was what I need - tried various forms of setAttrs too before, with no luck.
By the way, passing in a dict also works for setPosition()

Sorry about the typo - should have caught that before I sent it out.

Comment: Ah, good to know about the dict working also, I'll remove that from the answer since it wasn't the problem.